# How to return the list of selected values from multiselect in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

i have a multi select dropdown that take recoreds from database as options , so i need to get the id list of selected records

```
<div class="field">
    <label>Mailer</label>
    <div class="ui fluid multiple search selection dropdown">
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
        <div class="default text">Select Mailer</div>
        <div class="menu">

            @php
                use App\Mailers;
                $mailers=Mailers::all();
            @endphp

            @foreach ($mailers as $mailer)
                <div class="item">{{ $mailer->fname }}</div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you plan on using form controls? usually it consists of a form, select, and submit button, or you can use an xmlhttprequest as an alternative

Comment: yes i am using a form and i want to records id's

Comment: but what about the select list though? is it done through divs? or select option tags?, usually you click on the select box, pick out the ones you want and you press submit. then your PHP code (which is what the controller does, is process the input you made) does the response

Comment: First thing you need to add select tags with option, how ever it is bad practice to add php code in view, write code in controller and return the data  to the view .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use array in name attribute that will hold the selected options

```
<div class="menu">
    @php
        use App\Mailers;
        $mailers = Mailers::all();
    @endphp
    <select multiple name="mailId[]">
        @foreach ($mailers as $mailer)
            <option value="{{ $mailer->id }}">{{ $mailer->fname }}</option> 
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

As you are using a form you will get the form values in controller in Request object.
So in controller

```
foreach ($request->mailId as mail_id) {
    //here what you need to do with the ids.
}
```

> It's a bad practice to use php in blade/view. Load variables from your controller instead.

Comment: how to pass the list to the controller and manipulate each value of the list  ?